# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.thesis.joinerapp.Model.Joins

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i want to query my Firebase Database base on the value that i get from other activity.

```
private String tripID = "";
tripID = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("tripID");
JoinRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Join").child(tripID);
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Joins> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Joins>().setQuery(JoinRef,Joins.class).build();
```

Database Structure:
[image: Database Structure]

But it shows an exception

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type com.thesis.joinerapp.Model.Joins

Comment: You are suppose to add another pushUid after tripId

Answer (score 1):

While FirebaseUI can perform look ups of data for you, your data has to be in a very specific format for that.

If you want to show a subset of the number of trips, the index has to look like this:

```
"myTrips": {
    "tripID1": true,
    "tripID2": true
}
```

Where `tripID1` and `tripID2` are the `-L` keys that you have under `/Trip`.

You can find another example of this data in the FirebaseUI documentation on [showing indexed data](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data).

Answer (score 0):

when you want to use the FirebaseUi, your database structure should be like this.

```
{
    "Join" : {
        "tripID" : {
            "pushUid" : {
                "joinID" : "yourJoinID",
                "personCount" : "1",
                "tripID" : "yourTrioID",
                "uid" : "yourUid"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You need to **add** new root child which is `pushId`.